# Error con FloatingButton cuando ejecuto en el telefono

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Buenos días, ya tengo mi aplicacion terminada y en el emulador funciona de maravillas mas cuando la pasa al telefono y la ejecuto me presenta un error, adjunto la informacion a ver si me pueden ayudar con esto, puesto que e provado varias soluciones dadas en otros post y ninguna me ha funcionado, el problema es con los floatingButtons hasta donde entiendo

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Rv_Pedido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="458dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/btnFloatOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_ok"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Azul_clr"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/btnFloatSUMA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_suma"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Amarillo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/btnFloatAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_search"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Naranja"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/btnFloatMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_add"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Rojo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/precionoiva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="$ 0"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/precioiva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="$ 0"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_precioiva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Total + IVA :"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_precionoiva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Total sin IVA :"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> MANIFEST

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_dds"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Cliente" />
        <activity android:name=".Pedido" />
        <activity android:name=".Productos" />
        <activity android:name=".CierreOP"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

> BUILD

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //compileSdkVersion 25
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('jtds-1.3.1/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' // appcompat library
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

> Error

```
05-23 10:26:54.648 23065-23065/com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1, PID: 23065
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1/com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1.Pedido}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                    at com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1.Pedido.onCreate(Pedido.java:51)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1.Pedido.onCreate(Pedido.java:51) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.example.ddanthe.tpedidosv1.Pedido.onCreate(Pedido.java:51) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1723)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1792)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:998)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:989)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:96)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:1652)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:975)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:17538)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:17414)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:67)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:810)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:71)
                                                                                    at
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas la librería de soporte cambia la propiedad `android:backgroundTint`, a la correcta propiedad `app:backgroundTint` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
...
...
app:backgroundTint="@color/Azul_clr"
/>
```

Comment: gracias amigo, efectivamente esa es la solución

Comment: Un placer, saludos Diego.